# ¿Cómo hacer función con async y await?

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo la siguiente función que devuelve un `IQueryable<Cliente>` quiero implementarla con `async` y `await` de modo que el programa no se quede colgado ya que demora en realizar la consulta.

```
public IQueryable<Cliente> Buscarclientes(string DNI)
{
     CardEntities Model = new CardEntities();
     var consulta = from doc in Model.Documento
                    join clien in Model.Cliente on doc.Cliente_idCliente equals clien.idCliente
                    where doc.registro == DNI
                    select clien;

    return consulta;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Si devuelves un `IQueryable<T>` no tiene sentido hacerlo `async`  ya que lo único que devuelves es una expresión que represente al query a ejecutar y no el resultado de la evaluación de la expresión.

Si por el contrario deseas devolver los resultados de forma asíncrona entonces deberás devolver un `Task<IEnumerable<T>` o un `Task<List<T>` por ejemplo llamando al método `.ToListAsync()`

```
public Task<List<Cliente>> BuscarclientesAsync(string DNI)
{
     CardEntities Model = new CardEntities();
     return (from doc in Model.Documento
             join clien in Model.Cliente on doc.Cliente_idCliente equals clien.idCliente
             where doc.registro == DNI
             select clien)
            .ToListAsync();
}
```

En este caso no necesitas hacer `await` (ni marcar el método como `async`) porque ya el `.ToListAsync()` devuelve un `Task<T>`

Comment: Como lo recibiria al momento de llamar a la funcion?

Comment: `var result = await BuscarclientesAsync(dni);` (Esto dentro de un método marcado como `async`)

Comment: @byariel Si te sirvió la respuesta puedes marcarla como aceptada